# Circles not aligned/symmetrical , python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I see that the position and angle of the turtle cursor is correct after each circle, but there seems to be an offset when drawing the last circle. I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of the offset.

```
import turtle
import math
window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor('cyan')

loop = 90
angle = 4
step = 8
c = loop * step
r = ((c/2)/(math.pi))
d = c/(math.pi)
the_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
the_turtle.speed(500)
print(the_turtle.heading())
print(the_turtle.position())

for x in range(loop): 
    the_turtle.forward(step)
    the_turtle.left(angle)

print(the_turtle.heading())
the_turtle.penup()
the_turtle.setposition(0,r)
the_turtle.pendown()
print(the_turtle.position())

for x in range(loop):
    the_turtle.forward(step)
    the_turtle.left(angle)

the_turtle.left(180)
print(the_turtle.heading())
the_turtle.penup()
the_turtle.setposition(0,r)
the_turtle.pendown()
print(the_turtle.position())

for x in range(loop):
    the_turtle.forward(step)
    the_turtle.left(angle)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSVgf.png)

Comment: Can you please explain your code a bit more? What is it supposed to do, and what does it wrong? For me, the turtle draws 3 circles. Is it supposed to draw them next to eachother or is there something else wrong?

Comment: Seems the image I attached didn't work. Please see the link below, it shows you how my code is drawn.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfQu3.png

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables. Maybe you have float values and this makes problem. Or you use wrong value for last circle

Comment: problem is that you draw in different direction and this need first circles draw first line to right from 0 to +8 but last circle draw first line to left from 0 to -8. It needs `the_turtle.backward(step)` before last circe and it will draw first line from +8 to 0 - it will be in the same place as in other circles. BTW: probably if you try to draw rectangle then you should better see this problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you draw last circle  in different direction - so first and second circle draws first line to the right from 0 to +8 but last circle draw first line to the left from 0 to -8.

It needs `the_turtle.backward(step)` before last circe and it will draw first line from +8 to 0 - so it will be in the same place as in other circles.

BTW: probably if you try to draw rectangles then you should better see this problem.

---

```
import turtle
import math

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor('cyan')

loop = 90
angle = 360/loop  
step = 8

c = loop * step
r = ((c/2)/(math.pi))
d = c/(math.pi)

the_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
the_turtle.speed(500)

print(the_turtle.heading())
print(the_turtle.position())

for x in range(loop): 
    the_turtle.forward(step)
    the_turtle.left(angle)

print(the_turtle.heading())
the_turtle.penup()

the_turtle.setposition(0, r)
the_turtle.pendown()
print(the_turtle.position())

for x in range(loop):
    the_turtle.forward(step)
    the_turtle.left(angle)

the_turtle.left(180)
print(the_turtle.heading())
the_turtle.penup()
the_turtle.setposition(0, r)
the_turtle.pendown()
print(the_turtle.position())

the_turtle.backward(step)  # <----

for x in range(loop):
    the_turtle.forward(step)
    the_turtle.left(angle)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

---

To draw it without `backward()` you would have to first plot half step, next 359 full steps, and finally half step.

```
import turtle
import math

# --- functions ---

def circle(loop, step, angle):
    # half step
    the_turtle.forward(step//2)
    the_turtle.left(angle)

    # 359 full steps
    for x in range(loop-1): 
        the_turtle.forward(step)
        the_turtle.left(angle)

    # half step
    the_turtle.forward(step//2)
        
# --- main ---

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor('cyan')

loop = 90
angle = 360/loop  
step = 8

c = loop * step
r = ((c/2)/(math.pi))
d = c/(math.pi)

the_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
the_turtle.speed(500)

print(the_turtle.heading())
print(the_turtle.position())

circle(loop, step, angle)
    
print(the_turtle.heading())
the_turtle.penup()
the_turtle.setposition(0, r)
the_turtle.pendown()
print(the_turtle.position())

circle(loop, step, angle)
    
the_turtle.left(180)
print(the_turtle.heading())
the_turtle.penup()
the_turtle.setposition(0, r)
the_turtle.pendown()
print(the_turtle.position())

circle(loop, step, angle)
    
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me we can simplify things greatly if think of the two adjacent circles as a single figure eight:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import pi

steps = 90
step_size = 8
angle = 360 / steps

circumference = steps * step_size
diameter = circumference / pi
radius = diameter / 2

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('cyan')

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

for _ in range(2):
    for _ in range(steps):
        turtle.forward(step_size)
        turtle.right(angle)

    angle = -angle

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(radius)
turtle.pendown()

for _ in range(steps):
    turtle.forward(step_size)
    turtle.right(angle)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

As a side effect, this draws the figure centered vertically on the window, unlike the original.  Also, we can compute `angle` rather than use a constant.  And look up the valid arguments to the `speed()` method.

[image]